# random new entry django_session

Tags: mysql, django, phpmyadmin

For some reason, my django app keep inserting new entry into django_session even if no one is one the website. It will keep inserting until the mysql server crashes.

From phpmyadmin, I can see that 47% of querys are "set option" and only 25% are "select", but this application is suppose to be high select less write.

Comment: I checked and realized that session_data has many repeat. One session_data has over 1000 repeats, but they have different session_id

Answer (score 0):

You may use [custom management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).